# Highcharts: how to maintain the same order of category labels when bar chart changes to column chart

Tags: highcharts

I have a column chart, which has category labels Yes, No, Don't Care in xAxis. I also have two buttons which, when clicked, changes to a bar chart or vice versa. See the picture: [image]

However, when changed to bar chart, the labels on yAxis are, from top to bottom,  Don't Care, No, Yes. This new order is odd to users. I hope to still keep Yes, No, Don't Care (top to bottom) on the yAxis in the bar chart.

When a button is clicked, I have the following code for changing to bar chart:

```
    var chart = code for find the chart object
    chart.inverted = true;
    chart.xAxis[0].update({}, false);
    chart.yAxis[0].update({}, false);
    chart.series[0].update({
        type: 'bar'
    });
```

The following code is for changing to column chart:

```
    var chart = code for find the chart object
    chart.inverted = false;
    chart.xAxis[0].update({}, true);
    chart.yAxis[0].update({}, true);
    chart.series[0].update({
        type: 'column'
    });
```

How can I get the Yes, No. Don't care (top to bottom) order in the bar chart?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See the fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/xbhpjznq/3/)

```
$("#bar").click( function  (){
 var chart =  $('#container').highcharts();
 // Added code to share the fiddle
 });
```

Comment: Nishith, thanks a lot!!! By comparing your code with mine, I found out that my problem was caused by the reversed property of xAxis.

Comment: Exactly, those were reversed .sorry I didn't mentioned the issue and just posted fiddle with desired behavior

Comment: Thanks for your follow-up!